# Flow: refinement not work on custom type

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

For example here is my code:

```
export const handleRequestError = (error: (AxiosError<> | Error)) => {
  if (typeof error === Error) {
    errorNotification('Request Fail', error.message);
    console.log('Error', error.message);
  }
}
```

But when I run `yarn flow`. I always meet this error:

```
Cannot get error.message because property message is missing in AxiosError [1].

 [1] 10│ export const handleRequestError = (error: (AxiosError<> | Error)) => {
     11│   // General error
     12│   if (typeof error === Error) {
     13│     errorNotification('Request Fail', error.message);
     14│     console.log('Error', error.message);
     15│   }
```

It looks like that flow doesn't recognize that I have check condition to Error type. How can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 typeof error
```

is actually `"object"`, your check should be:

```
 error instanceof Error
```

Comment: Funny though that flow doesn't warn about the `typeof error === Error` ...

Comment: [ESLint would](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/valid-typeof). I guess Flow doesn't give an error because of [how it handles === checks](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2359).